# Recibir un array en ajax y recorrelo

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Lo que quiero es que esa consulta que traigo me la envié a ajax para poder hacer un condicional, pero necesito saber como recorrer la información que viene en ese array. espero me puedan ayudar.

Este es mi modelo con la consulta.

```
function Estadomascotas($documento){
    $this->db->select('count(mascota.estado) as deshabilitados, numMascotas');
    $this->db->from('mascota');    
    $this->db->join("detallemascotacliente", 'mascota.idMascota = detallemascotacliente.idMascota');
    $this->db->join("cliente", 'cliente.documento = detallemascotacliente.documentoCliente');  
    $this->db->where('documento', $documento); 
    $this->db->where('mascota.estado', 0);

    $consulta = $this->db->get();

    return $consulta->result();
}
```

Este es mi controlador

```
function numEstadoMascotas(){

    $documento = $this->input->post("documento");

    $data = $this->Model_cliente->Estadomascotas($documento);

    echo json_encode($data);


}
```

Este es mi Js

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/tienda/cliente/numEstadoMascotas",
                    data: {
                        documento: documento
                    },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data) {
                    
                        console.log(data);

                    }   

                });
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el resultado de `console.log(data)` y lo que has intentado hasta ahora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es tan fácil como en el success de la llamada ajax poner:

```
var datos = JSON.parse(data);
```

JSON.parse lo que hace es parsear el JSON que recibe para que puedas luego recorrerlo con un for o un forEach. Por ejemplo:

```
var datos = JSON.parse(data);
datos.forEach(function(value, index){
     console.log('Total deshabilitados: ' + value.deshabilitados);
     console.log('Numero de máscotas: ' + value.numMascotas);
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ferran me funciono, muy agradecido.